# Knitr: how to use citep control sequence inside code chunk option fig.cap?

Tags: captions, citing, knitr

I have a problem to include a citation into a code chunk option `fig.cap`, e.g.:  `fig.cap= Reprinted from \citep{Moran2008}`. When the `citep` control sequence is included in the option, the execution of the pdf file is halted.
I use natbib package for citations.
Is there some way to do this?

Whole code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt, english]{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\begin{document}
<<my_chunk, fig.cap= Reprinted from \citep{Moran2008}>>=
plot(iris)
@
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the way R treats string constants:  literal backslash must *always* be doubled, even inside quotes (by the way, please do not omit quotes!)

```
<<my_chunk, fig.cap='Reprinted from \\citep{Moran2008}'>>=
plot(iris)
@
```